# How to use the awk command in a loop to produce several thinned data files

Tags: bash, loops, awk

I have several large data files with 8 columns and 120,000 rows. Now I want to keep 1 line every 200 lines starting from the 100th line. I have the script file thin.sh as:

```
awk '(NR%200==100)' original_file > thinned_file
```

However, now I have 30 original files, which means I have to revise the command little by little for 30 times and the original files share similar names as:

```
data.0000.dat, data.0001.dat data.0002.dat, ..., data.0029.dat
```

I suppose there must be some way to embed the `awk` command into a loop to accomplish my goal, maybe something like:

```
for(i=0;i<30;i++);
do
    awk '(NR%200==100)' data.$i.dat > data.$i_thinned.dat
done
```

But I realize there're two digits of `00` in front of `$i` in the file names. Can I use `sprintf("%s")` or something? If so, how to arrange the order of `awk` and `sprinf`?
I use ubuntu and bash.

Comment: Just put all the filenames after `awk` or let your shell do it for you `awk '{...}' *.dat` You may have to change `NR` to `FNR`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With seq:

```
for i in $(seq -f %04g 1 29); do
  awk 'NR % 200 == 100' "data.${i}.dat" > "data.${i}_thinned.dat"
done
```

Alternatively with bash:

```
for i in {0001..0029}; do
```

The quotes are not strictly necessary in the first snippet because we know `$i` does not contain anything nefarious, but it's better to be paranoid about expansion in shell scripts. The braces in `"data.${i}_thinned.dat"` are necessary so the shell doesn't look for a variable `$i_thinned` to use. They are not strictly necessary in `"data.${i}.dat"` because shell variable names cannot have `.` in them, but consistency is nice.

Comment: I have tried you code, but it seemed not working. My final test files are `data.0003.127.dat`, `data.0006.127.dat`, `data.0009.127.dat` and `data.0012.127.dat`, so I changed the code as: `for i in {0003 0006 0009 0012}; do awk 'NR%200==100' data.$i.127.dat > $i_thinned.dat done`. But when I run the script in terminal, it says: `awk: cannot open data.{.127.dat (No such file or directory) `, `awk: cannot open data.0012.}.127.dat (No such file or directory) ` and except for the above two files, `0006` and `0009` are also thinned.

Comment: The brackets are for the expansion between 0001 and 0029. If you want to just pick a few select tokens, use `for i in 0003 0006 0009 0012`. Run `echo {0001..0029}` to see what the `{..}` does. If you want a general case with larger increments than 1, `seq` is probably the way to go, as in `for i in $(seq -f %04g 3 3 12)`

Comment: I have changed the code in `.sh` as I have mentioned " I changed the code as: for i in {0003 0006 0009 0012}; " . So you mean I need to remove the braces? Ah, I tried it, but the script only produces one file with the name"127..dat", actually I check the data inside and it should be the file `127.12_thinned.dat` then I deleted the `127` in `127.$i_thinned.dat `. and this time no thinned dat file was produced then.

Comment: Oh, I know. There should be braces around the `i` in `${i}` -- it's looking for a variable called `i_thinned`. That's what I get for not paying attention :P I'll edit that into the first loop.

Answer (score 0):

#### Ingedients(GAWK)

1 `FNR` - The record number in the current file
1 `match` - Matches a regex string and can capture groups into an array.
1 `print` - Prints following data(if none is provided then defaults to current record)
1 `*.dat` - All files ending with .dat in the current director.

---

#### Instructions

1. In the condition block check that the current record number in the current file when divided by 200 leaves a remainder of 100.
2. If it does then run the next block `{..}`
3. Take the current file name and match up to the last dot, capture everything before this with `(.*)` into array `a`.
4. Print into a file using the captured date `a[1]` with the extension `_thinned.dat`
5. Finally add `*.dat` to the end to read all .dat files in the current directory

---

#### Resulting code

```
gawk '(FNR%200==100){match(FILENAME,/(.*)\./,a);print >(a[1]"_thinned.dat")}' *.dat
```

---

Comment: @EdMorton Do you not need to close it ?

Comment: @EdMorton Ahh right, is that on all versions of gawk ?

Comment: @EdMorton The match won't work on other awks so i didn't think it would be a problem. Surely it will be less likely than not needing `close`. I'll add it anyway though just in case :)Also would it be possible to direct me to some documentation that says awk handles all file closing ? I can only find this page https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Close-Files-And-Pipes.html

Answer (score 0):

All you need is:

```
awk 'FNR==1{close(out); out=FILENAME; sub(/\.dat/,"_thinned&",out)} (FNR%200==100){print > out}' data.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].dat
```

I used `data.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].dat` as the file name globbing pattern instead of `data.*.dat` in case you rerun the script in the same dir where you previously generated all of the "_thinned" files.